# Your opinion about locally saving all posts on tex.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

I am considering using `wget -p -k -n Tex.stackexchange` and thus save all posts to some future emergency if I or the site goes offline.  Do you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, scraping the site like that is a quick way to "Too many requests from this IP address".

A [data dump](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) of all SE sites is available from Internet Archive, including

```
tex.stackexchange.com.7z    04-Mar-2019 16:44   484.3M
```

This file includes questions, answers, comments, and more: see 
[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677)

Comment: Hey, at least compressed, we are larger than unix.se and even among the top five (superuser.com is with 815M the biggest, followed by askubuntu.com, serverfault.se, and, interestingly, ru.se).

Comment: Math.SE is over 1G.

Comment: Oh, I apparently missed that one. math.se being the biggest is nevertheless remarkable.

Comment: @Daniel superuser.com is the biggest? What about `stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z 13.2G`? (and that is not even all of it)

Comment: Wow, many sites even are smaller than `stackoverflow.com-Votes.7z`, which is `997.3M`. Insane.

Comment: @Daniel I am not really sure what gets included in the dump, but if screenshots/images are included that may explain why TeX.SE is larger than others, given that a large amount of answers (but also questions) have images here. On Math.SE they use MathJax, but if that is included in the dump in rendered form (i.e., as images) then that also adds to the size of the archive.

Comment: @Marijn Images are not included in data dumps, they are hosted externally by Imgur. The questions and answers are contained in HTML format in the Posts table. The Markdown source is available in the PostHistory table. The link at the end of my answer has the details.